# Sensor input calibration for wider range

Tags: operational-amplifier, pic, sensor, adc, calibration

I get minimum voltage output from my sensor as 2.2V and max voltage as 2.65V. I want to change this voltage to 0-5V range so that the controller ADC can calibrate input in a wider range.

How can I do that through a circuit?
The microcontroller is a PIC 16F877A.

Can someone guide me, please?

Comment: As you tagged the question "operational amplifier" you already know the answer.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30719/analog-voltage-level-conversion-level-shift

Answer (score 0):

Presumably we don't want + - power supply for the amplifier.
So it will work from 5V. Thus, however, its output can never reach two values.
One is zero and the other is 5V. :)
It approaches a couple of ten mV, but never reaches.
To be accurate at the two extremes, the gain must be slightly reduced.
This will also be good here because we can use  10x gain.[image: erősítő]

The average value of the input voltage is 2.425 V.
We try to set this on the inverting input with resistors (14k, 14.953k).
Then the gain with resistors R3 and R8.
We get quite unusual values, so we use series resistors.
Thus, the 2.2V input will be 240mV and the 2.65V input will be 4.74V.

[image: erősítőkettő]

You can already find a lot of amplifiers that meet these requirements.
However, you should search among the RRO types.
Of course, it is not necessary to select the type used in the model.

There is even a spare in case the supply voltage is not exactly 5V.